# Displaying icon in mac statusbar with python

Tags: python, macos, statusbar

I have a script that just returns true/false depending on some conditions, and I need to display this status in the status bar/some topmost window, the script is written in python.

I tried to find a way to display a status bar icon with python but seems all existing wrappers are outdated. I feel that it is not very good solution to create a native app just for displaying an icon and control it with my script.

I thought about using GeekTool for mac, but it can display stuff only on the desktop. Since the desktop is hidden with some windows all the time, that's not very good solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Have found out that

```
import objc, from Foundation import *
from AppKit import *
from PyObjCTools import AppHelper
```

solves my problem